# Django failing to import app in a different directory

Tags: django

A codebase which is working in another local machine isn't working on mine and this is taking far more time that I have expected.

**Command to run the application**:
`python3 manage.py runserver --settings=config.settings.local`

**Directory**:

```
--- Config
----> Settings
----> urls.py
----> wsgi.py
----> asgi.py
----> __init__.py

--- Pybo
----> views
----> apps.py
----> urls.py 
----> views
------> indicator_views.py
------> profile_check.py
```

After running the command, I am encountering 404 Error saying "No Board matches the given query". If I try to view the definition of the imported app by clicking `from pybo.views import indicator_views, profile_check` inside the `/config/urls.py/`, the intellisense complains `No definition found for views`. Thus, I'm suspecting that the `config/urls.py` isn't correctly importing components located inside the other directory.

Is there a way that I can solve this? It's my first time using Django, and I believe the structure is a bit weirdly established but I was given this codebase and I should apparently start from what I have.

I also tried running in a venv, but it would complain that background-task isn't installed. And once I finish installing the package, it complains that `urls.conf` is deprecated so abandoned using venv.

Comment: A 404 Error indicates that your server is up and running. That is already a good sign. To me it seems like "Board" is an entry in the scheme of your database. Since you just started the project the issue might be, that no Boards are found in the database but the requested view needs a Board to display its content. Try to access other urls and check if the Error persists. Search the project for default data to populate the database with.

Comment: @Tarquinius Hi thanks for replying. I have tried accessing the other urls but they all return 404 errors. I made sure running makemigrate & migrations before starting the application.